# Retrieving specific user details from AD via c#/.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, active-directory, sspi

I am trying to retrieve `SamAccountName`,`Surname`,`GivenName` for users within a particular ADGroup using:

```
        PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
        GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, adgroup);

        foreach (Principal principal in group.Members)
        {
            samName = principal.SamAccountName;
            surName = principal.SurName;   <-- Intellisense gives error
            givenName = principal.GivenName;   <-- Intellisense gives error
        }
```

As I step thru the code and add watches in Visual Studio for the above, they display the correct information, but `principal.Surname` and `principal.GivenName` give the following error at compile:

'Principal' does not contain a definition for '____' and no extension method can be found

Can someone explain why I can see the information when  using codebreaks in the IDE and hover over the `principal` variable, but cannot access the attribute in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SurName` and `GivenName` are not public properties of type `Principal` according to the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principal(v=vs.110).aspx)

It looks like you need the `UserPrincipal` class to expose those properties, see the UserPrincipal [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal(v=vs.110).aspx)

I cannot verify 100% right now, but I think if you change

```
foreach (Principal principal in group.Members)
```

to

```
foreach (UserPrincipal principal in group.Members)
```

it should work

Comment: That did it.  Thanks!  Crazy that Visual Studio shows it as an attribute while watching the principal variable during run time.

Comment: The reason it does that is because the actual type is `UserPrincipal ` but you explicitly defined it as a `Principal`, which means at compile time your code can only access the values Principal has.  From the docs you can see that UserPrincipal inherits AuthenticablePrincipal  which inherits Principal.

Comment: Ah!  Now I know which direction to look in for future issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

The Principal class does not have a property Surname or GivenName
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principal(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I see that in the documentation, but how does Visual Studio IDE show it when watching the principal variable during run time is what I was trying to figure out. Very confusing.

Comment: see comment from maccettura, I think that he is correct the Principle class is an abstract class and UserPrinciple derives from it and add the properties that you need